# How to enable a checkbox in HTML when clicking on a different elements?

Tags: html, input, checkbox, label

I have a collapsible slider with a checkbox and a label:

`<input id="collapsible" class="toggle" type="checkbox">`

`<label for="collapsible" class="lbl-toggle">Impressum</label>`

When I click on the label, I can toggle between enable and disable, but I have some elements above the document and I want them to **only** enable the checkbox when I click on them.

Comment: In HTML the position of elements is important, I think that label should be first and input after, it is to begin, and try.

Comment: The label is just working fine, I just need an element to be able to toggle the checkbox on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an extra input, that is to say:
input type="submit" value="Submit"

Comment: I think I have expressed myself wrong. I want the other elements to **only toggle** the checkbox from my code above (id="collapsible") **on**. I can add another label to that element, but it will toggle between on and off. I want my original label to be a toggle with on/off, but I want another label that only toggles on to the checkbox.

Comment: You have to use javascript.